# Application links to false site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app i defined this route:

```
get 'nachricht/(:username)/(:model)/(:id)/(:department_kontakt)', to: 'messages#index', as: 'nachrichten'
```

Next in my index.html.erb i have this link:

```
<%= link_to department.bezeichnung, nachrichten_path(nil, nil, nil, department.id), :class => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary' %>
```

But instead of linking to:

```
 http://localhost:3000/nachricht?department_kontakt=2
```

It links to:

```
 http://localhost:3000/nachricht/2
```

How is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Why do you expect nachrichten_path create "nachricht?department_kontakt=2" when your route looks nothing like that?

Comment: I thought that when i only define this param it would appear like this

Comment: @bjelli here is a article about it: http://openbook.galileocomputing.de/ruby_on_rails/ruby_on_rails_09_002.htm chapter params! I hope you can learn something new!

Comment: I love to learn something new - but not about Rails 2 :-)  Not in 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding a new route:

```
get 'nachricht2/(:department_kontakt)', to: 'messages#index', as: 'nachrichten2'
```